# gmaps4rails1.5.0-Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Cannot get gmaps4rails1.5.0 to render map. gmaps4rails1.4.8 worked fine yesterday. Commented out config.action_view.debug_rjs=true in deveopment.rb. What needs to change to revert map to rendering?

Errors

```
Started GET "/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-01 16:42:10 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js"):


Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templa
/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Started GET "/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-01 16:42:10 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js"):


Rendered c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templa
/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v1.5.1 just released which should fix the bug. Sorry and thanks for reporting